# Problems with Delphi DLL IStream parameter calling from C++

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, istream, loadlibrary

I have DLL written on Delphi. I have only DLL without header file, so I load it dynamically. (to C++ project)

```
HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(L"LibName.dll");
if (!hLib) {
//Throw error
}
```

DLL provides functions:

```
function DataToFile(AddressName: PChar; Request: PChar;
  RequestSize: integer; ResultFile: PChar;
  ErrorBuf: PChar; ErrorBufSize: integer):BOOL;stdcall;

function DataToStream(AddressName: PChar; Request: PChar;
  RequestSize: integer; ResultStream: IStream;
  ErrorBuf: PChar; ErrorBufSize: integer):BOOL;stdcall;
```

My Visual Studio Code (C++):

```
typedef bool(__stdcall* f_DataToFile)(
    char*,  //AddressName: PChar
    char*,  //Request: PChar
    int,    //RequestSize: integer
    char*,  //FileName: PChar
    char*,  //ErrorBuf: PChar
    int);   //ErrorBufSize: integer);

typedef bool(__stdcall* f_DataToStream)(
    char*,  //AddressName: PChar
    char*,  //Request: PChar
    int,    //RequestSize: integer
    std::istream &, //ResultStream: IStream
    char*,  //ErrorBuf: PChar
    int);   //ErrorBufSize: integer);
```

...
Get funct. address:

```
//load DataToFile
f_DataToFile DataToFile = (f_DataToFile) GetProcAddress(hLib, "DataToFile");
if (!DataToFile) { //throw error 
}

//load DataToStream
f_DataToStream DataToStream = (f_DataToStream) GetProcAddress(hLib, "DataToStream");
if (!DataToStream) { //throw error
}
```

...
Set data:

```
char* AddressName = _strdup("127.0.0.1:1234");  //AddressName: PChar
char* Request = _strdup("<?xml request... >");  //Request: PChar
int RequestSize = strlen(Request);  //RequestSize: integer

char* ResultFile = _strdup("exportpath\\output.xml");  //FileName: PChar
char* ErrorBuf = new char[255]; //ErrorBuf: PChar
int ErrorBufSize = 255;  //ErrorBufSize: integer);

std::filebuf(buffer);
std::istream ResultStream(&buffer);
```

...
First function working correctly

```
bool reesult1= (DataToFile)(AddressName, Request, RequestSize, ResultFile, ErrorBuf, ErrorBufSize);
```

...
I have problems with second function execution -

```
bool reesult2= (DataToStream)(AddressName, Request, RequestSize, ResultStream, ErrorBuf, ErrorBufSize);
```

It is compiling, but gives Access Violoation on run.

Can someone help me to get - how to correctly work with IStream data type from (Delphi)?

When i declare ResultStream as nullptr pointer and call DataToStream function with to incorrect connection address, function return "Connection error" - so it is imported correctly and main question is returning IStream from function.

Answer (score 4):

Your translation of `IStream` is not correct. The DLL is using the [COM `IStream` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream). You can't replace that with C++'s `std::istream` class. You need to use a COM object that implements the `IStream` interface. To  access a file as an `IStream`, you can use the Win32 [`SHCreateStreamOnFileEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatestreamonfileex) function, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau!

```
HRESULT GetFileStream(
_In_ LPCWSTR fullFileName,
_Outptr_ IStream** stream)

{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

// Create stream for writing the file
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(
        fullFileName,
        STGM_CREATE | STGM_WRITE | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
        0, // default file attributes
        TRUE, // create file if it does not exist
        NULL, // no template
        stream);
}
return hr;
}
```

in typedef:

```
IStream *,  //ResultStream: IStream
```

..

```
LPCWSTR filename = L"path\\to\\file.txt";
IStream* ResultStream = NULL;
HRESULT hr = GetFileStream(filename, &ResultStream);
```

..

```
bool result = (CallRK7XMLRPCToStream)(AddressName, Request, RequestSize, ResultStream, ErrorBuf, ErrorBufSize);
```

here is a good example of using SHCreateStreamOnFileEx:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/AppxPackingCreateBundle/cpp/CreateBundle.cpp